# How to model perfectly elastic collisions using force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, simulations

I want to have elastic collisions in my Newtonian physics simulator, but in the one physics class I've taken we only used momentum when analyzing elastic collisions, and my simulator is totally force-based.

If two pointlike objects are colliding with given velocities and masses, what forces should I have them exert on each other in order to simulate a perfectly elastic collision?

Comment: There's a reason you analyzed such collisions in terms of momentum. The required force is a dirac-delta function of the distance between the particles, which is a strange mathematical object students normally don't encounter until their first quantum mechanics course.

Comment: Oh, wow. That's really upsetting. Do you know if there's a good heuristic of some kind? I don't want to break my simulation's "purity" and directly edit velocity.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the right person to ask for advice on computer simulations. :(

Comment: Is this a 1D or 2D/3D simulator?

Comment: @Kyle It's a 2D simulator

Comment: Follow up question: do your particles have finite size or are they point-like? And, if you happen to know, what what is the typical ratio $\bar{v}\Delta t/r$ where $\bar{v}$ is the typical particle speed, $\Delta t$ is the simulation timestep and $r$ is the particle radius. If this ratio is $<<1$ you're in good shape and you might be able to get some force-based collision prescription working, but if it's $>1$ you're in trouble.

Comment: Okay, awesome, that ratio is much less than 1. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

This question seems to be closer to the Computational Science group rather than Physics. In brief, any central potential force would do this - Lennard-Jones, Coulomb (better use screened Coulomb), the exact form doesn't matter; any of these forces will result in motion conserving total mechanical energy and momentum so an elastic "collision" motion will follow inevitably. There is a whole field of computational science called Molecular Dynamics (MD) where details of this are worked out, I suggest checking out
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_dynamics#Potentials_in_MD_simulations

Comment: This comes with some caveats I think. If the time resolution of the simulation is too long, particles can potentially move through each other without an collision-like interaction. This is easy to deal with in 1D (don't let particle order change, go back and decrease timestep instead), but in 2+ dimensions it gets tricky. I'd also recommend an approximated potential that actually goes to zero at some reasonable radius instead of an exponential (or other) decay to save on computation, but whether that's important depends on how many particles are being simulated.

Comment: The Lennard-Jones potential has a minima point, which might cause attractive forces to develop between particles. Wouldn't really want that when you want to simulate normal force between particles. Although you could cleverly set the minima to be such that the particles seem to *touch* at that point.